# Approval Process Dicrete conditions

Tags: approval-process

I am new to salesforce and hence the below question might be naive for you. 
Say in the approval process my requirement is if the Discount is 10% go for approval to Mr. X. If the dicount is 20 % go for approval to Mr Y only without going through Mr. X.

So do i need to create two approval process with different entry criteria or can it be done in  a single approval process?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in single Approval process. You will need to [create two steps](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=approvals_creating_approval_steps.htm&language=en) and each step will have different conditions.
Step 1 will have condition for 10% and step 2 will have condition for 20%.
There are many resources available to learn basics of approval process, few of them are :

1. [Short Video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fM3xHN8M9-8)
2. [Detailed Video tutorial from Dreamforce](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m8XmfBQDSpY)
3. [Some useful examples](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=approvals_useful_approval_processes.htm&language=en)